# 'bcryptJS' works fine than 'bcrypt' (mock-aws-s3,aws-sdk,mock error) in Vue + Vite

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, vite, bcrypt

I've created a login component that will call loginService function which takes username and password But before calling the API call password is hashed using bcrypt. If I remove bcrypt hash code everything is working fine but with bcrypt function, I'm getting the following error.

```
X [ERROR] Could not resolve "mock-aws-s3"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:43:28:
      43 │     const AWSMock = require('mock-aws-s3');
         ╵                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "mock-aws-s3" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove
  this error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this
  failure at run-time instead of bundle-time.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "aws-sdk"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:76:22:
      76 │   const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
         ╵                       ~~~~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "aws-sdk" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
  error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at
  run-time instead of bundle-time.

X [ERROR] Could not resolve "nock"

    node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/s3_setup.js:112:23:
      112 │   const nock = require('nock');
          ╵                        ~~~~~~

  You can mark the path "nock" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this
  error. You can also surround this "require" call with a try/catch block to handle this failure at
  run-time instead of bundle-time.
```

Not sure how mock-aws-s3,aws-sdk,mock are related here.

```
// Login Component
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Welcome to the WarBank</h1>
    <div>
      <form class="tile" @submit.prevent="login">
        <input
          type="text"
          v-model="userCredentials.userName"
          placeholder="username"
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          v-model="userCredentials.passWord"
          placeholder="****"
        />
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, reactive } from "vue";
import { User } from "../interface/login";
import { fetchLoginService } from "../services/loginService";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Login",
  components: {
    OpenAccount,
  },
  setup() {
    const userCredentials: User = reactive({
      userName: "",
      passWord: "",
    });
    const login = async() => {
      fetchLoginService(userCredentials.userName,userCredentials.passWord);
    };
    return {
      userCredentials,
      login,
    };
  },
});
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```

Service File

```
import axios from 'axios';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
export async function fetchLoginService(userName:string, password:string){
    const loginURL = "URL here"
    const hashpassword = await bcrypt.hash(password,12);
    axios.post(loginURL,{userName,password:hashpassword}).then((response:any)=>{
        console.log(response);
    }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

vite.config.ts

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['bcrypt'],
  },
})
```

**This problem can be solved if I replace 'bcrypt' with 'bcryptjs' in import. But why these kinds of problems are seen here?**
I have found similar issues raised here - [link](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/discussions/11026)